# 0xc000007B application was unable to start

Tags: easyphp

I am trying to run EasyPHP on Windows 10 (64 bit) system. Initially the error was regarding msvcr110.dll missing, which I resolved somehow. Now its showing the error of 0xc00007b unable to start program correctly. I have tried to run the compatibility troubleshoot as well as run as administrator option. Its just not working. Any other effective solutions ?

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when you have mix of x86 and x64 libraries installed. You should probably uninstall all x86 versions of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables and install their x64 bit counterparts (just google them and make sure you download 64 bit version of that library).